# La fonction de « en » dans « Sans en faire la cause unique de la Révolution française, »

Tags: grammaire, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

Je ne comprends pas pourquoi on a besoin de  « en » dans « Sans en faire la cause unique de la Révolution française, ». On a déjà la phrase « de la Révolution française », ou pas?

Comment: Pourrait dire aussi : "sans faire de ce facteur/ceci/cela la cause unique de la Révolution française".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La fonction *grammaticale* de `en` est ici [**complément d'objet second (COS)**](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/guide/complement-d-objet-second-cos) :

> faire **de xxx** la cause...

C'est comme un Complément d'Objet Indirect (COI) mais dans une construction qui prend deux compléments (`rendre [son argent] [à César]`, `dis-[lui] [de venir]`...) on nomme le COI "second", ou COS.

Answer (score 4):

***En*** ne fait pas référence à la Révolution française, mais à l'un des facteurs ayant contribué à sa survenue, présenté dans la phrase précédente :

> Tout laisse à penser que **ce dynamisme démographique**, inconnu au cours des siècles précédents, a effectivement contribué à la **stagnation des salaires agricoles** et à la **progression de la rente foncière** dans les décennies menant à la déflagration de 1789. (Source: [Thomas Piketty](https://gabriellagiudici.it/thomas-piketty-le-capital-au-xxie-siecle/))